# git throwing error while checking out from master branch

Tags: git, version-control

I pulled chnages from git repo with

`git pull` on master branch

git status shows ok

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/var/www/site1$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Then i try `git checkout test-branch`

Then i get this

```
 git checkout test-branch
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
.........
.......
Aborting
```

then i again go back to master branch

what can be the issue

Comment: error describes that you have some changes in master branch that need to commit.

Comment: @Suleman but when i do git status on master branch it says nothing to commit

Comment: Yes, but you have _untracked_ files that would be overwritten by the commit your checking out, i.e. the commit contains files that aren't tracked by the currently checked out commit.

Answer (score 0):

You have files that would be overwritten by checking out `master`.

Try this:

```
git checkout -f master
```

Documentation about `checkout -f`:

> When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. This is used to throw away local changes.